i am tryin to display my gesture predictions(from edge impulse) on to my mobile phone through BLE using Pi Pico W
Using C++ SDK for Pi-Pico. I made the gesture prediction code. but now i was trying to utilize the dual core capability of Pi Pico and see predictions on phone using BLE. Since there is not much guidance out there. using BLE and Dual core is difficult.
Ps. this is for my first year project.
Modified SPP counter of BT-Stack to give simple text message over Bluetooth. Now tried integrating it with my edge impulse prediction code on dual core. its not working.
#include<stdio.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "pico/time.h"
#include "hardware/i2c.h"
#include "hardware/gpio.h"
#include "ei_run_classifier.h"
#include "hardware/pwm.h"
#include "hardware/pio.h"


#include "pico/cyw43_arch.h"
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "btstack_run_loop.h"

#include "pico/multicore.h"

#define SCL 1
#define SDA 0

#define I2C_PORT i2c0

void mpu6050_reset();
void transfer(int a);
void gesture(void);
void mpu6050_read(int16_t accelerometer[3]);
int btstack_main(int argc, const char * argv[]);

static bool debug_nn = false;
volatile bool timer0_occur=false,timer1_occur=false;
const uint LED_PIN = 15;

void gesture(void){
   
    gpio_init(LED_PIN);
    gpio_set_dir(LED_PIN, GPIO_OUT);


    //Initialize I2C port 0 and configuring Pins 0 and 1 for MPU6050
    
    i2c_init(I2C_PORT,100000);
    gpio_set_function(SCL,GPIO_FUNC_I2C);
    gpio_set_function(SDA,GPIO_FUNC_I2C);
    gpio_pull_up(SCL);
    gpio_pull_up(SDA);
    mpu6050_reset();

    ei_impulse_result_t result = {0};


   int16_t accelerometer[3];


    if (EI_CLASSIFIER_RAW_SAMPLES_PER_FRAME != 3) {
        ei_printf("ERR: EI_CLASSIFIER_RAW_SAMPLES_PER_FRAME should be equal to 3 (the 3 sensor axes)\n");
    }

      while (true) 
    
    {
    gpio_put(LED_PIN,1);  //Indicating wait operation
    ei_printf("\nStarting inferencing in 1 seconds...\n");
    sleep_ms(1000);
    gpio_put(LED_PIN,0);
    ei_printf("Sampling...\n");

    // Allocate a buffer here for the values we'll read from the IMU
    float buffer[EI_CLASSIFIER_DSP_INPUT_FRAME_SIZE] = { 0 };

        for (size_t ix = 0; ix < EI_CLASSIFIER_DSP_INPUT_FRAME_SIZE; ix += 3) {
        // Determine the next tick (and then sleep later)
        //uint64_t next_tick = micros() + (EI_CLASSIFIER_INTERVAL_MS * 1000);
        uint64_t next_tick = ei_read_timer_us() + (EI_CLASSIFIER_INTERVAL_MS * 1000);
    
        mpu6050_read(accelerometer);
        buffer[ix + 0]= accelerometer[0];
        buffer[ix + 1]= accelerometer[1];
        buffer[ix + 2]= accelerometer[2];
        //IMU.readAcceleration(buffer[ix], buffer[ix + 1], buffer[ix + 2]);
        
        sleep_us(next_tick - ei_read_timer_us());
        //delayMicroseconds(next_tick - micros());
    }
   /* if(accelerometer[2]>=8000)
    multicore_fifo_push_blocking(4);
    else if(accelerometer[2]<=-7000)
    multicore_fifo_push_blocking(5);*/
    // Turn the raw buffer in a signal which we can the classify
    signal_t signal;
    int err = numpy::signal_from_buffer(buffer, EI_CLASSIFIER_DSP_INPUT_FRAME_SIZE, &signal);
    if (err != 0) {
        ei_printf("Failed to create signal from buffer (%d)\n", err);
        break;
    }

    // Run the classifier
    ei_impulse_result_t result = { 0 };

    err = run_classifier(&signal, &result, debug_nn);
    if (err != EI_IMPULSE_OK) {
        ei_printf("ERR: Failed to run classifier (%d)\n", err);
        break;
    }
      
    if(result.classification[0].value>=0.8)
    {
        ei_printf("Prediction: Circle\n");
        multicore_fifo_push_blocking(0);
        

    }
    else if(result.classification[1].value>=0.8)
    {
        ei_printf("Prediction: Idle\n");
        multicore_fifo_push_blocking(1);
    
        
    }
    else if(result.classification[2].value>=0.8)
    {
        ei_printf("Prediction: Left-Right\n");
        multicore_fifo_push_blocking(2);
    
    }
     else if(result.classification[3].value>=0.8)
    {
        ei_printf("Prediction: Up-Down\n");
        multicore_fifo_push_blocking(3);
    

    }
    else
    {
        ei_printf("Error 404\n");
    }

    #if EI_CLASSIFIER_HAS_ANOMALY == 1
    ei_printf("    anomaly score: %.3f\n", result.anomaly);
    #endif
    }
}
    
    


int main()
{
    stdio_init_all();

    multicore_launch_core1(gesture);

    if (cyw43_arch_init()) {
        printf("cyw43_arch_init() failed.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    
    // run the app
    btstack_main(0, NULL);
    btstack_run_loop_execute();

    
    return 0;
}

thats the main.cpp;
and here is the bt code
    /*
 * Simple SPP Server - Send Static Text over Bluetooth
 */

#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "pico/multicore.h"
 
#include "btstack.h"

#define RFCOMM_SERVER_CHANNEL 1


void transfer();
static void packet_handler (uint8_t packet_type, uint16_t channel, uint8_t *packet, uint16_t size);


static uint16_t rfcomm_channel_id;
static uint8_t  spp_service_buffer[150];
static char lineBuffer[30];
static btstack_packet_callback_registration_t hci_event_callback_registration;

static const char* text_message = "Bluetooth Initialized";

void transfer(){

    while(true){
        uint32_t a = multicore_fifo_pop_blocking();

    if(a == 0){
        snprintf(lineBuffer, sizeof(lineBuffer), "Circle");
        printf("%s", lineBuffer);
        rfcomm_request_can_send_now_event(rfcomm_channel_id);
    }
     if(a == 1){
        snprintf(lineBuffer, sizeof(lineBuffer), "Idle");
        printf("%s", lineBuffer);
        rfcomm_request_can_send_now_event(rfcomm_channel_id);
    }
     if(a == 2){
        snprintf(lineBuffer, sizeof(lineBuffer), "Left-Right");
        printf("%s", lineBuffer);
        rfcomm_request_can_send_now_event(rfcomm_channel_id);
    }
     if(a == 3){
        snprintf(lineBuffer, sizeof(lineBuffer), "Up-Down");
        printf("%s", lineBuffer);
        rfcomm_request_can_send_now_event(rfcomm_channel_id);
    }
    }
}

static void spp_service_setup(void) {
    // register for HCI events
    hci_event_callback_registration.callback = &packet_handler;
    hci_add_event_handler(&hci_event_callback_registration);

    l2cap_init();

#ifdef ENABLE_BLE
    // Initialize LE Security Manager. Needed for cross-transport key derivation
    sm_init();
#endif

    rfcomm_init();
    rfcomm_register_service(packet_handler, RFCOMM_SERVER_CHANNEL, 0xffff);  // reserved channel, mtu limited by l2cap

    // init SDP, create record for SPP and register with SDP
    sdp_init();
    memset(spp_service_buffer, 0, sizeof(spp_service_buffer));
    spp_create_sdp_record(spp_service_buffer, 0x10001, RFCOMM_SERVER_CHANNEL, "PicoW RP2040");
    sdp_register_service(spp_service_buffer);
    printf("SDP service record size: %u\n", de_get_len(spp_service_buffer));
}


static void packet_handler (uint8_t packet_type, uint16_t channel, uint8_t *packet, uint16_t size) {
    UNUSED(channel);

    bd_addr_t event_addr;
    uint8_t   rfcomm_channel_nr;
    uint16_t  mtu;

    switch (packet_type) {
        case HCI_EVENT_PACKET:
            switch (hci_event_packet_get_type(packet)) {


                case RFCOMM_EVENT_CHANNEL_OPENED:
                    if (rfcomm_event_channel_opened_get_status(packet)) {
                        printf("RFCOMM channel open failed, status %u\n", rfcomm_event_channel_opened_get_status(packet));
                    } else {
                        rfcomm_channel_id = rfcomm_event_channel_opened_get_rfcomm_cid(packet);
                        mtu = rfcomm_event_channel_opened_get_max_frame_size(packet);
                        printf("RFCOMM channel open succeeded. New RFCOMM Channel ID %u, max frame size %u\n", rfcomm_channel_id, mtu);
                        // send the text message once the channel is opened
                        rfcomm_send(rfcomm_channel_id, (uint8_t*) text_message, (uint16_t) strlen(text_message));
                    }
                    break;
                case RFCOMM_EVENT_CAN_SEND_NOW:
                    rfcomm_send(rfcomm_channel_id, (uint8_t*) lineBuffer, (uint16_t) strlen(lineBuffer));  
                    break;
                
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

int btstack_main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;

    transfer();
    spp_service_setup();
    
    gap_discoverable_control(1);
    gap_ssp_set_io_capability(SSP_IO_CAPABILITY_DISPLAY_YES_NO);
    gap_set_local_name("PicoW RP2040");

    // turn on!
    hci_power_control(HCI_POWER_ON);
    
    return 0;
}

that gesture(); seems to be running in the second core; but now the bluetooth is not connecting

We need a bit more information than "its not working". What is not working? Do you receive an error message? Please [edit] your question to add all relevant information and source code

sry, its my first time asking question on the site, edited the query, @MichaelKotzjan
